# Using perceptually uniform colormaps in Mayavi volumetric visualization

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, mayavi, colormap, perception

AFAIK Mayavi does not come with any perceptually uniform colormaps. I tried naively to just pass it [one of Matplotlib's colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) but it failed:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import multiprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plasma = plt.get_cmap('plasma')

...
mlab.pipeline.volume(..., colormap=plasma)
```

> TraitError: Cannot set the undefined 'colormap' attribute of a 'VolumeFactory' object.

---

Edit: I found [a guide](https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~dic1e13/mayavi-colour-palettes.html) to convert Matplotlib colormaps to Mayavi colormaps. However, it unfortunately doesn't work since I am trying to use a volume using a perceptually uniform colormap.

```
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

values = np.linspace(0., 1., 256)
lut_dict = {}
lut_dict['plasma'] = get_cmap('plasma')(values.copy())

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]
s = np.sin(x*y*z)/(x*y*z)

mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s), vmin=0, vmax=0.8, colormap=lut_dict['plasma'])  # still getting the same error
mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

...

Comment: Found a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970659/scalar-fields-visualisation-in-python

Comment: As far as I can tell, this seems to be a bug. I've filed a bug report here: https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/371

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting it as the `colormap` argument, if you set it as the `ColorTransferFunction` of the volume, it works as expected.

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.util import ctf
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

values = np.linspace(0., 1., 256)
x, y, z = np.ogrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]
s = np.sin(x*y*z)/(x*y*z)

volume = mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s), vmin=0, vmax=0.8)
# save the existing colormap
c = ctf.save_ctfs(volume._volume_property)
# change it with the colors of the new colormap
# in this case 'plasma'
c['rgb']=cm.get_cmap('plasma')(values.copy())
# load the color transfer function to the volume
ctf.load_ctfs(c, volume._volume_property)
# signal for update
volume.update_ctf = True

mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

While the previous answer by like444 helped me partially with a similar problem, it leads to incorrect translation between colormaps. This is because the format in which matplotlib and tvtk store color information is slightly different: Matplotlib uses RGBA, while ColorTransferFunction uses VRGB, where V is the value in the shown data that this part of the colormap is assigned to. So by doing a 1-to-1 copy, green becomes red, blue becomes green and alpha becomes blue. The following code snippet fixes that:

```
def cmap_to_ctf(cmap_name):
    values = list(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
    cmap = cm.get_cmap(cmap_name)(values)
    transfer_function = ctf.ColorTransferFunction()
    for i, v in enumerate(values):
        transfer_function.add_rgb_point(v, cmap[i, 0], cmap[i, 1], cmap[i, 2])
    return transfer_function
```